# Is ZSKIPLIST_MAXLEVEL(64) enough for 2^64 elements？

Tags: redis, skip-lists

I have learned about skiplist from Skip Lists: A Probabilistic Alternative to Balanced Trees recently. I think 64 levels with p=0.25 should have 4^64 elements( If p = 1/2, using MaxLevel = 16 is appropriate for data structures containing up to 2^16 elements.--quote from A Probabilistic Alternative to Balanced Trees). But when I check the Redis server.h, I see

define ZSKIPLIST_MAXLEVEL 64 /* Should be enough for 2^64 elements */

define ZSKIPLIST_P 0.25      /* Skiplist P = 1/4 */.

Am I wrong or the config wrong？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right. It is fair to say that server.h defines a MAXLEVEL higher than necessary.

The probability that a particular element reaches a level at least `k` is `p^k`, and the probability that any of the `n` elements reaches a level at least `k` is `n·p^k`.

Redis uses the skip list for sorted sets, and it uses it in conjunction with a hash map. The hash map (`dict`) has a capacity of `2^64-1` elements (ready for, not ever tested in practice). Hence the comment on `ZSKIPLIST_MAXLEVEL`.

It follows that if we use `N = 2^64` as an upper bound on the number of elements in the skip list, Redis could have used ZSKIPLIST_MAXLEVEL = 32.

The nodes allocate memory up the level they actually got when *rolling the dice*. Only the first, null node uses the ZSKIPLIST_MAXLEVEL. The impact: 512 bytes of extra memory per sorted list (of 129 entries or more - before, it uses a ziplist, see `zset-max-ziplist-entries` config setting).

The other side effect is the chance a node would get an unnecessarily high level, but the odds get really low really fast as we go up beyond the 32nds level.

I think it is worth fixing IMO, for those 512 bytes.